# Intermittent issue of receiving emails when emails are sent using "mutt" email client in Linux

Tags: linux, shell-script, redhat-enterprise-linux, bash-scripting, mutt

To send an email to a specific set of users, I am currently using mutt (command line based email client).

Below is the command that I have used in my shell script to send an email:

```
echo "Initiating bulk load now " | mutt -x -s "Bulk loading of records" abc@xyz.com -a 20100421_log.txt < /dev/null
```

When I am trying to send an email with the help of the above command through shell prompt, I am receiving the email.

But when I am trying to send an email with the help of the same command through shell script, I am receiving the email intermittently.(Let's say: If the script is executed at 8:30 PM, I am not receiving the email but when the same script runs again at 9:30 PM, I am receiving the email, that too is sporadic.)

What could be the reason of receiving emails intermittently?

The shell script is currently scheduled to run every hour through cron expression.

```
Linux distribution: Oracle Linux Server release 6.10
Job scheduler: cron
```

Comment: Is mutt configured to use SMTP directly or is it configured to use /usr/sbin/sendmail? The latter almost always has information in /var/log.

Comment: The configuration file for mutt is .muttrc. Do I have to check the configuration in the configuration file in the home directory of the user from whom I am executing the shell script or in the root user's home directory?

Comment: Only set from = "user@domain.com" is present in the configuration file along with the alias name for the email ids to whom the email needs to be sent. There are no SMTP server details like SMTP url. SMTP password. Also I did not find anything related to sendmail.

Comment: If muttrc configuration file is not having details of the SMTP server and /usr/sbin/sendmail, then how come I am getting the email if I am executing the command through shell prompt?

Comment: If it has no specific configuration, then it is simply passing the email to /usr/sbin/sendmail, that's the default behavior for "traditional" mail apps. So investigate that – it should be keeping logs in /var/log. (Note that the 'sendmail' tool might be provided by many different software, e.g. Postfix or Exim or indeed the original Sendmail.)